# Derivate of Neural Network respect to input

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convex, relu

I have a neural network like this

$x=\text{input}$
$z_1=W_{1x}\cdot x+b_1$
$h_1=\text{relu}(z_1)$
$z_2=W_2\cdot h_1+W_{2x}\cdot x+b_2$
$h_2=\text{relu}(z_2)$
$y=W_3\cdot h_2+W_{3x}\cdot x+b_3$

input and weights are matrices

Now I want the derivation repect to the input x.
I used the chain rule and get:

$W_3 \cdot \text{diag}(\text{RELU'}(h_2)) \cdot (W_2 \cdot \text{diag}(\text{RELU'}(h_1)) \cdot W_{1x}+W_{2x})+W_{3x},$
with $\text{RELU'}(x)=1 \text{ if } x>0, \text{else } 0$

I am very unsure about the derivation, is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
if I use the h-derivate like this

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for very small h I get a different result than with my derivation.

My neural network has two inputs, so I use the h-derivate once for $x_1$ and once for $x_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your network looks something like this (renamed some parameters to avoid confusion):

[image]

Now:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dJ}{dx} = &\frac{dJ}{dy} \frac{dy}{dz} \frac{dz}{dh} \frac{dh}{dx}+ \frac{dJ}{dy} \frac{dy}{dz} \frac{dh}{dx}\\
& = \frac{dJ}{dy} \frac{dy}{dz} \frac{dh}{dx} \frac{dz}{dh}+ \frac{dJ}{dy} \frac{dy}{dz} \frac{dz}{dx}\\
& = \frac{dJ}{dy} \frac{dy}{dz} (\frac{dh}{dx} \frac{dz}{dh}+ \frac{dz}{dx})\\
\end{align*}
$$

At this point, you are only left with the actual calculations of the single derivatives, which seemed correct in your question... you might just be missing a final ")" (I've also added the derivative of the loss with respect to the output layer, but you might not need it depending on what you are doing with the gradient)

Comment: Did you change h and z in your picture or why is z in front of the output? So you say my derivation is correct, but then I have the following problem: I wanted to check the derivation with the h-derivative and got a different result.

Comment: @Gaweiliex yes, the names do not correspond... what do you mean with h-derivative? you have some problem in the notation that you have posted, some of those are scalar products, other must be matrix multiplications

Comment: I Edit my Question for better Visualisation what i mean with h-derivate. You're right with the notation i use the derivative in my Matlab script so this souldn't lead to any issue.

Comment: I find my mistake! The derivate is right. I had a mistake in my script Thanky You!

Comment: @Gaweiliex perfect, good luck with your project!